Return the object of correspond key value pair in python
I have recieved a JSON response from an API
[ {
        "@type": "activityLogEntry",
        "runContextType": "REST_API_V2",
        "entries": [
            {
                "@type": "activityLogEntry",
                "entries": [],
                "subTaskEntries": [],
                "logEntryItemAttrs": {
                    "CONSUMED_COMPUTE_UNITS": "0.0",
                    "releaseVersion": "4500"
                },
                "sessionVariables": {
                    "$$batch_name": "Taskflow_Fact_Order_Tracking",
                    "$$status": "Already Running",
                    "$$sub_area": "UPS"
                },
                "totalSuccessRows": 0,
                "isStopped": "false",
                "transformationEntries": [
                    {
                        "@type": "transformationLogEntry",
                        "txInstanceName": "src_batch_log"
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "transformationLogEntry",
                        "affectedRows": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "totalSuccessRows": 0,
        "stopOnError": false,
        "isStopped": "false"
    },
    {
        "@type": "activityLogEntry",
        "runContextType": "REST_API_V2",
        "entries": [
            {
                "@type": "activityLogEntry",
                "entries": [],
                "subTaskEntries": [],
                "logEntryItemAttrs": {
                    "CONSUMED_COMPUTE_UNITS": "0.0",
                    "releaseVersion": "4500"
                },
                "sessionVariables": {
                    "$$batch_name": "Taskflow_Fact_12222",
                    "$$status": "Already Running",
                    "$$sub_area": "UPS"
                },
                "totalSuccessRows": 0,
                "isStopped": "false",
                "transformationEntries": [
                    {
                        "@type": "transformationLogEntry",
                        "txInstanceName": "src_batch_log"
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "transformationLogEntry",
                        "affectedRows": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "totalSuccessRows": 0,
        "stopOnError": false,
        "isStopped": "false"
    },
    {
        "@type": "activityLogEntry",
        "runContextType": "REST_API_V2",
        "entries": [
            {
                "@type": "activityLogEntry",
                "entries": [],
                "subTaskEntries": [],
                "logEntryItemAttrs": {
                    "CONSUMED_COMPUTE_UNITS": "0.0",
                    "releaseVersion": "4500"
                },
                "sessionVariables": {
                    "$$batch_name": "Taskflow_Fact_12",
                    "$$status": "Already Running",
                    "$$sub_area": "UPS"
                },
                "totalSuccessRows": 0,
                "isStopped": "false",
                "transformationEntries": [
                    {
                        "@type": "transformationLogEntry",
                        "txInstanceName": "src_batch_log"
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "transformationLogEntry",
                        "affectedRows": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "totalSuccessRows": 0,
        "stopOnError": false,
        "isStopped": "false"
    },
    ]

I want the array element to be returned which has key "$$batch_name" and the value "Taskflow_Fact_Order_Tracking".
I tried getting the key value.. but wasn't able to return the entire array element.
The output should return the first element of the array. because it has  "$$batch_name": "Taskflow_Fact_Order_Tracking",
I am particularly looking for a solution in Python.
Thank you

Can you share your attempt? along with the actual and exact expected output?

How to navigate a dictionary is a fundamental requirement for anyone writing Python code. I recommend Getting started

The following code uses a list comprehension to iterate over the parsed JSON array. The next() function retrieves the first matching element where the $$batch_name is "Taskflow_Fact_Order_Tracking".
import json

# Parse the JSON data
activity_logs = json.loads(data)

# Filter the entries
matching_entry = next((entry for entry in activity_logs
                      if entry["entries"][0]["sessionVariables"]["$$batch_name"] == "Taskflow_Fact_Order_Tracking"), None)

# Print the matching entry
print(json.dumps(matching_entry, indent=2))

Result:
{
  "@type": "activityLogEntry",
  "runContextType": "REST_API_V2",
  "entries": [
    {
      "@type": "activityLogEntry",
      "entries": [],
      "subTaskEntries": [],
      "logEntryItemAttrs": {
        "CONSUMED_COMPUTE_UNITS": "0.0",
        "releaseVersion": "4500"
      },
      "sessionVariables": {
        "$$batch_name": "Taskflow_Fact_Order_Tracking",
        "$$status": "Already Running",
        "$$sub_area": "UPS"
      },
      "totalSuccessRows": 0,
      "isStopped": "false",
      "transformationEntries": [
        {
          "@type": "transformationLogEntry",
          "txInstanceName": "src_batch_log"
        },
        {
          "@type": "transformationLogEntry",
          "affectedRows": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "totalSuccessRows": 0,
  "stopOnError": false,
  "isStopped": "false"
}

